# ng-grid headerRowTemplate hides bootstrap dropdown

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, overflow, ng-grid

I am using a Bootstrap dropdown in a table header but it is just partly visible.

I have found that this is caused by `ngHeaderContainer` using a CSS property of `overflow:hidden`.

I override this property in my CSS as follows:

```
.ngHeaderContainer { overflow: visible !important; }
```

The problem is that my table contains a lot of columns and it is required to use horizontal scroll bar to see them all. When scrolling data in the table to the right, the header stays fixed and it is not scrolled.

I have implemented a couple of workarounds where I am overriding the property only after `focus` and rolling back on `blur` but that does not help either.

If the data in the table are scrolled to the right and I set `ngHeaderContainer` to visible then the header is corrupted and is visible, just like it is when the data hasn't been scrolled (from first column).

It will not help if I set

```
.ngHeaderCell { overflow: visible !important; }
```

because `ngHeaderContainer` is the parent and does not allow to show the content.

Did anybody notice a similar issue?

Comment: Any solutions for now?

Comment: This is a general issue, and not related to the use of BootStrap.

Comment: Does your table header have a fixed height on it? I'd start there

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue,
`.ngHeaderContainer {overflow:hidden}` should remain the same
in the css write

```
.ngViewport{overflow: auto;}
```

this worked for me this ll enable the scroll at the bottom of the viewport.